# Reduce subquery to join

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I don't understand how to optimize my subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM rp_clientAffectationHistory as T1
WHERE rp_clientAffectationHistoryID in (SELECT MAX(rp_clientAffectationHistoryID)
        FROM rp_clientAffectationHistory as T2
GROUP BY `rp_clientID`)
AND `rp_userID` = 57
```

I have many duplicate entries for the same "rp_clientID"; I want only records which have the latest rp_clientAffectationHistoryID.

Comment: What's error with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is something like:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Rp_Clientaffectationhistory AS T1
left join Rp_Clientaffectationhistory as T2 on (T1.Rp_Clientid = T2.Rp_Clientid) and T1.Rp_Clientaffectationhistoryid < T2.Rp_Clientaffectationhistoryid
where T2.Rp_Clientaffectationhistoryid is null
and T1.Rp_Userid = 57
```

Does it help?

Comment: Also can see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get only one entry for every `rp_clientID` -

The one thing you missed is to check `rp_clientID` inside the inner query -

```
SELECT *
  FROM Rp_Clientaffectationhistory AS T1
 WHERE Rp_Clientaffectationhistoryid IN
       (SELECT MAX(Rp_Clientaffectationhistoryid)
          FROM Rp_Clientaffectationhistory AS T2
         WHERE T1.Rp_Clientid = T2.Rp_Clientid
         GROUP BY Rp_Clientid)
   AND Rp_Userid = 57
```

is it what you were looking for?

Comment: Well, my query is working fine. I only want to replace my subquery by a JOIN :)

Answer (score 0):

For Sql server, try:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by rp_userID order by rp_clientAffectationHistoryID desc) Rnum 
    FROM rp_clientAffectationHistory
    WHERE rp_userID = 57
)x
WHERE Rnum=1
```